# Sum of ints below long's max value returns negative?

Tags: java, long-integer

I have 5 objects, `a`,`b`,`c`.`d` and `e`. The 5 objects hashcodes are as follows:

```
a => 72444
b => 110327396
c => 107151
d => 2017793190
e => 68574749
```

As you can see, all are positive values.
However, when I sum them up into a `long`-variable, the result comes out negative:

```
long sum = a+b+c+d+e;
System.out.println(sum);     // prints -2098092366
```

The sum of these ints far below the max-value of `long` (9223372036854775807), yet it yields a negative result. Why?

Comment: What type are the variables a through to e?

Comment: One-word String-variables for testing purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens because your variables are all `int`s, so you to `int` addition (which overflows), and then the final result is converted to `long`.

You can fix this by casting the first variable to `long`:

```
long sum = (long)a + b + c + d + e;
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 2):

Integer values can be -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. The sum actually exceeds the max value and trancted for `numeric overflow`.

```
int x = 2147483647;
x++;
System.out.println(x);
```

It prints - `-2147483648`